Pella windows from 1985 replacement
I want to replace my 1985 Pella aluminum clad windows. It looks like there is no window stop as it's one solid frame. What looks like a stop/trim is a single piece and can't be separated. The outside aluminum clad is under the siding. How the heck do I replace these?

Your question could be enhanced with inclusion of some photos to help illustrate the issues.

If you are attempting to replace windows that were originally installed using nail fins to secure the window to the outside of the building sheathing before any siding was installed you have to carefully consider how to approach this. Windows of this type are referred to as "new construction" type. There are "replacement" type windows but these generally are designed to install inside the jamb frames of the original windows.
Options to replace windows with the "new construction" type that have nail fins have several options as follows:

Defer any window replacements until such time that all windows and siding will be replaced at the same time. A project like this typically  strips off the old siding down to the building sheathing so that the original windows can be removed and replaced.
Trim back the siding around the existing windows to expose the nail fins so that the windows can be removed. Once the new windows are installed an added window trim frame is installed around the windows to cover the nail fins and merge up to the siding. How this is handled will depend greatly upon the type of the existing siding whether that be vinyl, aluminum, T111 plywood or cement board type.

